# AS3-External SWF loads audio, but not video

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When I try to display an external SWF, the audio plays, but the display is nothing but a big white screen. I can load the SWF directly from the project library and it loads with video, so I know the SWF is good. I know the SWF is there because the audio is playing, but I can't understand why the video is not showing up.

Here's my code:

```
[Embed(source = "../lib/Destiny_Introduction.swf", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
public var introClass:Class;
```

======lots of irrelevant code in between========

```
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
context.allowCodeImport = true;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.loadBytes(new introClass(), context);
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff including adding the loader to a MovieClip and adding that as a child, adding the loader's content as a child, Event.COMPLETE calls, a combination of all three, but they all yield the same result. What I have noticed is that the width and height of the loader is zero, as was those of the MovieClip when I tried adding the loader to that, so that may have something to do with it, but other than that, I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `mimeType` to `symbol` like so,

```
[Embed(source = "../lib/Destiny_Introduction.swf", symbol="LinkageIdentifierInSourceSWF")]
public var IntroClass:Class;

var scene1:MovieClip = new IntroClass();
addChild(scene1);
scene1.play();
```

Comment: It says the definition for the symbol is not found.

Comment: Infact, you need a symbol with the same name (Linkage Identifier in Library) in Destiny_Introduction.swf. This symbol will have timeline animation.

Comment: Now instead of showing nothing, the display resets to the first frame of the movie (that is, the frame that displays immediately at the start of the movie) instead of the SWF itself. (The frame it displays isn't even part of the SWF!)

Comment: Edit: I fixed that (bad document class) but it's back to showing nothing.